# Ransack search as scope for related records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ransack

I have `Report` `Expense` and `User` models.

User has many reports.
Expense belongs_to report.

I want to be able to use the result of my ransack search as a scope for the next queries.
I am searching like so:

```
@q = Report.search(params[:q])
@reports= @q.result(distinct: true)
```

I might be passing filters like report.user_id = xx and want them to affect all queries forward.

Put simply, how can i get to something like:

```
@reports.expenses
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *[map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)* method.

> Invokes the given block once for each element of self.
>
> Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

In your case that would be:

```
@reports.map(&:expenses)
```

Comment: undefined method `name' for # Expense::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fe4c08d44e0> Can't call any methods on @expenses, such as @expenses.sum(&:cost)

Comment: This is a whole new question, I can't help you without getting more information.